# Live preview to actual upload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a website using HTML5, CSS, minimal JavaScript and bootstrap.  Before when uploading my site with only HTML CSS and Javascript there were no issues, however after starting to use bootstrap uploading the code caused errors.

The error is as follows; 
1. Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

I understand JavaScript needs jQuery, however I do not know what to add in at that point since I have been taught to leave bootstrap files alone.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. In the linked question, the OP was doing writing his own Javascript to include jQuery — most people don't need to do that and the answer below will solve their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include jquery before the bootstrap js file, but you have the bootstrap js included like:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Before it you have to include jquery. Example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```